# Laravel Cashier Stripe API method calls is an optional per-request apiKey

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I hope some one can help me, Im using Laravel 5.2 and Cashier 6, and Im getting this error

Api in RequestOptions.php line 77:
The second argument to Stripe API method calls is an optional per-request apiKey, which must be a string, or per-request options, which must be an array. (HINT: you can set a global apiKey by `Stripe::setApiKey(<apiKey>)`)

but all the API of stripe are ok, thanks

Comment: Please post the code where you call the API

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same error. For me it was because my config was cached before I added the stripe keys so the config that Laravel was working with didn't include the stripe keys yet.

A simple `php artisan config:clear` should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks kielabokkie, I already tried all artisan commands and no luck

Answer (score 1):

Please check .env file.
Do you have this constant?(it should be only STRIPE_SECRET, another name give a problem)

```
STRIPE_SECRET = pk_test_--------------------
after that check app/services.php file
```

you should have stripe configuration

```
'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' =>  env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET')
    ],
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I don't use the .env file, I put the data directly

Comment: You should use  .env file because in Laravel 5.2 core Billable.php in line 470 getStripeKey() use from .env file, if it not defined static, please check it, Hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you for this comment @VaheGalstyan , this helped me. The docs say to use the services.php config file, but as you suggested it indeed only reads the env file.